# Should I joint-index an ActiveRecord polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, polymorphic-associations, indexing

I have a metric table that I expect to be very large.  It has a polymorphic association so that it can belongs_to other models that want to record some metric.  I typically index association columns like this to speed up association loading.  [I've heard people talking about joint-indexing this association](http://codeshooter.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/handling-database-indexes-for-rails-polymorphic-associations/).  This looks like:

`add_index :comments, [:commentable_type, :commentable_id]`

[But I've also heard counsel against creating indexes of low-cardinality](http://mattfleming.com/node/192), because the payoff of the index doesn't offset the overhead of maintaining it.  Since the _type half of my polymorphic association will probably only have 4-5 values across the millions of rows, I'm inclined to only index on the _id portion of the polymorphic association. I will probably create some additional joint-indexes using the _id column and some other unmentioned integer and datetime columns, but I won't include the _type in these indexes either.

Is this what you would do/recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, this is worth benchmarking before and after adding the index, on a realistic data set - realistic in size and data.

However, you're not creating an index on a field with just a few values.  The index is on the *combination* of the two fields, which is likely to have a *lot* of different value combinations. The index on the combined fields is a smart idea.

Answer (score 3):

It is best practice to put the most selective field first when creating an index on multiple fields. Since you only have 4-5 values of `commentable_type`, you would be better off doing:

```
add_index :comments, [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "most selective"?

Comment: @GMA it's very probable that you'll have tons of each type records, but number of types will be pretty limited, meaning there are only handful of rows with same commentable_id value, while thousands and thousands of rows with same commentable_type, which means that commentable_id is more selective